# cp without overwriting destination permissions

Tags: linux, cp

How do you use the `cp` command without changing the target file's permissions?  For example:

```
cp /tmp/file   /home/file
```

I don't want to change `chown` and  `chgrp` on `/home/file`.

Comment: It's not clear whether you are asking about preserving the source permissions or the target permissions. You've also cross-site spammed to SuperUser.

Comment: For the record, the "preservation" options are in reference to the **source**. `cp -p` makes the target attributes match (thereby preserving) the source attributes.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this page. cp by default ought to preserve the target files permissions and user:group because it opens the target in update mode and retaining its inode. So it's not clear to my why the answers don't indicate this.

Comment: This question is moot. GNU `cp` default behaviour is as desired by this question, as [demonstrated here](https://serverfault.com/a/1048378/322507).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you've only opened [the manual for `cp`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cp)...

The next will not overwrite the file permissions and ownership + groupship:

```
cp --no-preserve=mode,ownership /tmp/file /home/file
```

Note that root privileges are needed if you want to preserve the ownership and groupship.

An excerpt from the manual:

> ```
>   --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
>       preserve   the   specified   attributes   (default:  mode,owner-
>       ship,timestamps), if possible  additional  attributes:  context,
>       links, xattr, all
> ```

Comment: Not exactly what the author wanted. `--no-preserve` makes sense if used after `--preserve` (or its aliases), otherwise it doesn't affect the behavior of `cp`. The author wanted to keep the file mode of an existing target file and only overwrite its contents

Comment: Ex: replace ssh host keys `cp --no-preserve=mode,ownership ssh* /etc/ssh/`. This makes the secret keys world-readable.

Comment: The man page's --preserve explanation is IMHO nonsensical as it does  not make it clear preserve what: The source or target attributes

Comment: `--no-preserve=all` is default. And by default [GNU `cp` doesn't update target permissions anyway](https://serverfault.com/a/1048378/322507).

Answer (score 13):

`cat` will work, too:

```
cat /tmp/file > /home/file
```

Comment: does it work for binary files too ?

Comment: @beppe9000 yes, `cat` outputs whatever it inputs.

Comment: For an answer that works with `sudo`, [see here](https://serverfault.com/a/1048378/322507)

Answer (score 4):

By default, GNU `cp` (version 8.32) will NOT overwrite destination permissions, so the question is moot:

```
% ls -li
total 8,192
19392015 -rwxrwxrwx 1 ravi ravi 4 Jan  3 16:54 bar*
19392014 -rw-r--r-- 1 ravi ravi 4 Jan  3 16:46 foo
% cp foo bar
% ls -li
total 8,192
19392015 -rwxrwxrwx 1 ravi ravi 4 Jan  3 16:57 bar*
19392014 -rw-r--r-- 1 ravi ravi 4 Jan  3 16:46 foo
%
```

In the case where the destination file is not writable (even though the directory is), `cp` will say:

```
cp: cannot create regular file 'dest-file': Permission denied
```

---

Other options besides `cp`:

`cat` will preserve the inode and permissions of the destination file:

```
cat file-with-new-data > file-to-overwrite
```

However, redirections won't work with `sudo`.

If you want to `sudo` and keep the destination permissions, use this:

```
< file-with-new-data sudo tee file-to-overwrite > /dev/null
```

This is equivalent to the more verbose:

```
cat file-with-new-data | sudo tee file-to-overwrite > /dev/null
```

Comment: I verified cp version 8.26 also keeps the permissions/owner/group of the file being overwritten.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use even better **install** program from GNU coreutils that has been made for this particular purpose. Please note it is not able to recurse (no -R or -r option).

http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/install-invocation.html

Comment: I didn't see a switch for this to preserve the target's ower or group. Just force it to a new value.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use permission-related switches at all, especially `--no-preserve`, because it behaves strangely:

good:

```
[il@localhost Downloads]$ sudo cp ssh_host_* /etc/ssh/
[il@localhost Downloads]$ ls -l /etc/ssh
total 604
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     581843 Oct 20  2017 moduli
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       2276 Oct 20  2017 ssh_config
-rw-------  1 root root       3907 Oct 20  2017 sshd_config
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys    227 Oct  2 12:26 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root        172 Oct  2 12:26 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys    411 Oct  2 12:26 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root        100 Oct  2 12:26 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys   1679 Oct  2 12:26 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root        392 Oct  2 12:26 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

bad:

```
[il@localhost Downloads]$ sudo cp --no-preserve=mode,ownership ssh_host_* /etc/ssh/
[il@localhost Downloads]$ ls -l /etc/ssh
total 604
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     581843 Oct 20  2017 moduli
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       2276 Oct 20  2017 ssh_config
-rw-------  1 root root       3907 Oct 20  2017 sshd_config
-rw-r--r--. 1 root ssh_keys    227 Oct  2 12:27 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root        172 Oct  2 12:27 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r--. 1 root ssh_keys    411 Oct  2 12:27 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root        100 Oct  2 12:27 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-r--r--. 1 root ssh_keys   1679 Oct  2 12:27 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root        392 Oct  2 12:27 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

Answer (score -2):

The *cp* doesn't override permissions by default. 
If you want to make sure permission won't be overridden, use

```
cp --preserve=mode,ownership /tmp/file /target_dir_where_file_resides
```

Comment: That actually forces overwriting of the target permissions -- it preserves the permissions of the source file.